# Execute update command in MySql while overriding sql_safe_updates option

Tags: mysql

I need to run a script with update commands which do not specify the record IDs, so I know I must turn the flag of sql_safe_updates to OFF.

Yet, I need to restore the flag to its previous state.

Is there a way to hold the flag's value in a temporary parameter, then run my updates and restore it to its initial value?

(I will need to keep the script for deployment procedure, so I cannot change the flag's value manually every time it runs)

UPDATE:
That is about the script I have:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
UPDATE offensedb.offenses set Status = 6 , ClosingReason = 1 WHERE Status = 1;
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
```

Comment: What do you mean with "_with a script which does not specify the record IDs, so I know I must turn the flag of sql_safe_updates to OFF._"? Can you show us the script please?

Comment: Ok I updated to show some of my script if you find it helpful

Comment: So you say that Status is not a key in the offenses table? This is why you need to turn safe updates off?

Comment: That is more precise, yes, that is what i meant! :)

Comment: You don't need to turn it on again after. This command will affect only this query instance. Note that these are two queries: how do you run them in the application?

Comment: This two queries will be a part of a bigger script, written by more than one developers, It would be safer if I restore the flag just after my queries, so that the rest of the script does not have a "hole" of potential unsafe updates. So, do you know of a way to store just the value of the flag??

Comment: what is wrong with this approach?

Comment: Maybe nothing is wrong, but I will stick with my question: "Is there a way to hold the flag's value in a temporary parameter, then run my updates and restore it to its initial value?" If you know the answer, please reply and I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

After examining a dump file of mysql I came across these commands:

```
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE
-- some other sql commands there...
SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE
```

So I figured out the answer to my question would be:

```
SET @SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=@@SQL_SAFE_UPDATES;
UPDATE offensedb.offenses set Status = 6 , ClosingReason = 1 WHERE Status = 1;
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = @SQL_SAFE_UPDATES;
```